# Problem understanding Turing Halting problem

Tags: turing-machines

As I understand it in simple language the proof of this goes

Take a program (called oracle below) that will stop if the program it is examining never halts and never halts if the program it is examining halts.

Using this oracle program to examine itself results in a contradiction ...

The thing I do not understand is, why should the oracle not work as follows.

The program says 'never halts' if the program being examined never halts and 'halts' if the program being examined halts?

No contradiction there?

My tentative answer to this issue is that my second program could be used to generate the original program and hence expose the contradiction.

Comment: Yes, you could use your alternative oracle to implement the original oracle, which then still leads to the contradiction. As far as I know that's actually a more common way of laying out the proof. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Proof_concept

Comment: Thanks. I think that must be it. From reading Turing's work, he uses a lot of prose to present stuff which I like. Especially for discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the light of no other answers forthcoming. The objection is solved by using the fact that the simple program could be used to generate the said oracle and hence the contradiction is still there.